# Как сделать значок элемента в QListWidget нужного размера?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qicon, qlistwidgetitem

Пытаюсь добавить к элементам в `QListwidget` иконку.

Чтобы было вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установка значка не проблема. Проблема с его размером.

Как его правильно расположить? 
Если можно напишите простой набросок кода как это делается. Спасибо.

Comment: Такие вещи на виджета через делегаты, к примеру, делаются. Рассматривали возможность использования Qt Quick / QML? Там такие вещи делаются очень просто, давно игрался с qml и сделал список наподобии вашего: https://github.com/gil9red/ListFiles

Comment: Я пока изучаю python и задал вопрос конкретно по нему. Я понимаю, что есть отдельные языки, с помощью которых, наверно, это проще делается, но я их не знаю. И я понятие не имею, о чем вы написали. Прости те за глупость. Так, что если сможете, то подскажите, как это на пайтоне реализовать .

Comment: Qt Quick / QML являются частью самого Qt, да и задали вы вопрос не по питону, а по Qt

Comment: Метки. В них дело.

Comment: qt quick / qml относятся к qt, а значит и к pyqt5. Ладно, закрыли тему :) Если захотите сами погуглите что это и как с ним работать, вот вам статья: https://habr.com/post/326268/ А в первом моем комментарии есть ссылка на проект и там есть те самый .qml файлы

Comment: Для меня это очень сложно пока. Но все равно спасибо и позже обязательно посмотрю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы изучаете QListwidget, обратите внимание на

```
listWidget.setIconSize(QSize(46, 46))
```

Вот небольшой пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def clicked(self,item):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "ListWidget", "Вы выбрали: "+item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    listWidget  = ListWidget()
    listWidget.resize(550,200) 

    listWidget.addItem("Item 1")
    listWidget.addItem("Item 2")
    listWidget.addItem("Item 3")

    item = QListWidgetItem()
    icon = QIcon('E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png')
    item.setIcon(icon)
    item.setText(" QListWidget \n https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=QListWidget")
    listWidget.addItem(item)
    listWidget.setIconSize(QSize(46, 46))
    listWidget.setFont( QFont( "Times", 12, QFont.Black ) )

    listWidget.setWindowTitle('Пример QListwidget')

    listWidget.itemClicked.connect(listWidget.clicked)

    listWidget.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во, то что нужно. Спасибо большое)