# Как можно сделать интерфейс для создание карточки пользователя, с фото и дополнительной информацией?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, qlabel, qlistwidget

Делаю свою программу для распознавания лиц. Есть проблема с интерфейсом. 
Нужно сделать вывод на интерфейс идентифицированного пользователя в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Делаю весь интерфейс на *PyQt5*, база данных *sqlite3*, изображения лиц из базы находятся в отдельной папке.

Подскажите какими средствами можно реализовать такой вывод?

Comment: Большая картинка и информация справа от нее -- это например QLabel (с помещенной на него картинкой) и пользовательский виджет (используется QFormLayout с набором виджетов-полей). Их можно разместить на QSplitter, чтобы двигать разделителем, либо не заморачиваться и на QHBoxLayout. Список картинок ниже, думаю лучше через специально настроенный QListWidget сделать.

Comment: Список картинок внизу не нужен, именно нужны такие карточки, и вот они чтобы представляли из себя нечто вроде строк, то есть по порядку чтобы появлялись виджеты в виде листа, как раз и думаю что подойдёт QListWidget, но вот как эту картинку с информацией передать туда? Получается QLabel встроить в QListWidget.

Comment: не знаю, я по другому представлял этот интерфейс и ваше решение все решить через QListWidget вызывает недоумение. Я так понимаю, что при клике на картинку в списке картинок внизу, она должна отобразиться влевой части, а справа появится по ней информация?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать нормальный значок элемента в QListWidget?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/854381/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-qlistwidget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как может выглядеть ваш пример с эффектом FlowLayout

Попробуйте изменять размеры окна. Думаю, что вам понравиться.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.textQVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel  = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)

        self.allQHBoxLayout  = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel      = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.iconQLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80)                   # +++
        self.iconQLabel.setMaximumSize(80, 80)                   # +++

        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)


    def setTextUp (self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown (self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath).scaled(80, 80))  # + scaled(80, 80)

class exampleQMainWindow (QtWidgets.QListWidget):    #QMainWindow):     # +++ / ---
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        #self.myQListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)

        # +++
        self.resize(420, 300)
        self.setFrameShape(self.NoFrame) # Нет границы
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)   # Слева направо
        self.setWrapping(True)           # Эти 3 комбинации могут достичь того же эффекта, что и FlowLayout
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)

        for index, name, icon in [
            ('No.1', 'Лена', 'E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Image/lena.png'),
            ('No.2', 'Петя', 'E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'),
            ('No.3', 'Вася', 'E:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg'),
            ('No.4', 'Петя', 'E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'),
            ('No.5', 'Вася', 'E:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg'),
            ('No.6', 'Лена', 'E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Image/lena.png'),
            ('No.7', 'Петя', 'E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'),
            ('No.8', 'Вася', 'E:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg'),
            ('No.9', 'Петя', 'E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'),
            ('No.10', 'Вася', 'E:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg'),
            ]:
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(index)
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(icon)
            myQListWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)  #.myQListWidget)
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            #self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            self.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            #self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)
            self.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересно! Только у меня проблема, как я могу динамически добавлять эти виджеты в QListWidget? У меня появляется первая строка как положено, а остальные пустые, поможете?

Comment: Формируйте новый вопрос. Публикуйте код. Мир не без добрых людей!

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался с решением, спасибо за наводку, gil9red, вы очень помогли.
Может кому нибудь в будущем потребуется такое же решение, вот пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel  = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)
        self.allQHBoxLayout  = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel      = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)


    def setTextUp (self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown (self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))

class exampleQMainWindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.myQListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        for index, name, icon in [
            ('No.1', 'Андрей',  'icon.png'),
            ('No.2', 'Петя', 'icon.png'),
            ('No.3', 'Вася',  'icon.png')]:
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(index)
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(icon)
            myQListWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пример вывода:

[image: Test image]